# how to create a crossword puzzle shape in android

Tags: android

I want to create a crossword puzzle using android studio. the problem that I run into is I can't figure out a good way to draw the crossword puzzle [the crossword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq0C2.jpg)

upon selecting a word from that shape. the user will access an interface that is designed specifically for that word. [where to enter the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYeIb.png)

The problem I have is how to actually create that crossword shape, especially since I need it to be created dynamically afterwards based on the supplied data.

After 15 days of research all I can find are those possibilities:

1. Using Table layout with each cell representing a character. But this approach is not appropriate and not optimate and create many problems.
2. Using  GridView with the unused cells set to be invisible. this is better but I think there is a better way than creating Grids only to set most of it to invisible.*
   **I am sure there is a better way, but can't figure it out.

I know I have to give a code sample for what I have but I can't even do that till I know what approach I need to create this. If there is any suggestion to make my question clear that will be welcomed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Neither.  This calls for  custom view for the word grid.  While you can probably get it to work without one, it's going to look very amateurish, and you're going to be very hacky.  Instead, you'll want a totally custom view doing its own keyboard input handling.  Unless this is like a school project where looks and UX don't matter and you just need it done.

Comment: i need it to look professional and everything matters. Do you suggest to extend a particular view or is it better to create one by extending the class view? Sorry if question not clear

Comment: Just extend View.  You're going to want to do a custom onDraw.  There's some implementations where you have 2 or 3 custom views (one for the Grid extending ViewGroup and laying out its children, one for text cells, and possibly one for blacked out cells).  That could provide a nice separation of concerns, letting the GameGridView handle layout of cells and letting the cells handle display of text, keyboard and touch interaction.